# How to edit SharePoint 2013 sites in SharePoint designer 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

How can I edit SharePoint 2013 sites in SharePoint designer 2010, has anybody know any tricks and tips.

Please share it , will greatly appreciate

Comment: You can install SPD2010 and SPD2013 side by side so this shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late answer but actually, it's just a Windows update that blocks SPD 2010 access to 2013 sites.
Take a look at "[How To Open A 2013 Site In Sharepoint Designer 2010](http://365.webbrewers.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=25) "

Comment: Please, provide an abstract from the link. Your answer is not helpful if this link breaks :)

Comment: The link is http://365.webbrewers.com/Pages/webbrewerstest2.aspx. What kind of abstract do you want? The whole article?

Comment: When browsed from my cellphone I only get an error message stating that the link is unsupported for example. So the main idea of the workaround found on the link would be great

Comment: I can only respond to comments so I'll just say here that I prefer 2010 (design view and all) and have no problem editing 2010 and 2013 sites in SPD2010. All it takes is undoing a MSFT update that blocks 2013 sites opening in SPD2010.

Comment: The post referenced was moved to: http://365.webbrewers.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=25

Comment: You should edit your post with that information to make it easy to find!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem so,

To edit the sites, you need to use the same version of SharePoint Designer which matches the version of Microsoft SharePoint Server.

You need Designer 2007 for SP 2007, Designer 2010 for SP 2010, and Designer 2013 for SP 2013.

As a work around, pls follow the below, but its not recommended.

I did the following,

1. Open a SharePoint 2013 team site with SharePoint Designer 2010;
2. Change the default master page to v4.master in SPD2010;
3. create a custom list in SPD2010;
4. Open the allitems.aspx page for the custom list in SPD2010 and customize the xsltlistviewwebpart on it, adding some field to display on the view;
5. change the default master page back to seattle.master;
6. open the allitems.aspx page for the custom list in browser, my customization done with SPD2010 have effect

Comment: Ok thanks Karthik, will try to do  like as you wrot above!

Comment: Karthik isn't work on my environment((

Comment: ha..ha..ha!  I have done already  a bit later , i mean  mid of june  last year , now   i can use SPD2010  for developing SPSite 2013.

Comment: What's been missed here is O365 users have been forced onto the 2013 SP platform. A lot of businesses still use XP and can't install SPD2013, so without the fix mentioned are stuck. There is no issue with editing SP2010 or 2013 in SPD2010. Msft simply tried to block that from happening for no good reason, that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Designer is free, so to avoid problems down the road, just download it and install it. You can have both spd2010 and spd2013 on the same PC, so I really think you should just get the 2013 version.

Comment: Vlad thanks for advice,  i know that  SPD 2013 is way for editing   sites , but my  condition is  somthing like that ,  i need  view  and cod of my site too  , untill the last month i had edit my SPSite 2013  in SPD 2010 , but now its  shown me the message , that i need to  run SPD 2013 .:( thats why i asked her  for any tricks and  info.  for  how can  i do  it !

Comment: I have done already a bit later , i mean mid of june last year , now i can use SPD2010 for developing SPSite 2013.